# How to do linked select list in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have object `$scope.animals` and two select list on page:

```
<select ng-model="type">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>


<select ng-model="animals">
  <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in animals">{{value}}</option>
</select>
```

How to display all option in select list by default from object, and if select option from first select list then sort second list by id?

For example, if I select `value="1"` from `ng-model="type"` then in second list is appeared option where `key = value="1"`

I can use `ng-show` with condition in option `ng-repeat`, but it will be work, only when I select first list

**Updated question:**
I found easy way to do it:

```
<option value="{{value.id}}" ng-repeat="(key, value) in animals">{{value.name}}</option>
```

For this I need to apply `filter` like as:

```
| filter:value.type = selectedValueFromFirstList
```

How I can do it?

Edit:

I use:

```
 <option ng-show="selected == value.id" value="{{value.id}}" ng-repeat="(key, value) in animals">{{value.name}}</option>
```

How I can to display options by default? Now it works only when I have `selected`

Comment: What does key = value="1" mean? Your second select makes no sense. animals can't be the ng-model and the list of options. ng-model contains the *selected* option. Change its value, and the selected option will change.

Comment: Updated question, look please

Comment: @Caur So did u get answer?

Comment: No, problem is not resolved. I will try to do himself, but have problem - I updated question

Comment: Your question is not clear. Explain what u want to achieve?

Comment: I need to make two select list related, but display options in second list by default

Comment: Do you mean based on the value of first selected list item?

Comment: Yes, base on selected value from first list. Look please my latest edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all don't use ng-repeat for lists instead use [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).

Now to set the default value of second list based on first list you need to set the `ng-model` for the first list. So whenever you make selection in the list item the selected value will be in ng-model. By using it you can set the second list item default value. Also you can set the default value for the first list item by setting value in the controller.

See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/KN9xx/493/)